# console.logs in onClick handleSubmit do not print out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a login component in React 18.x front end to take input of username and password, and then send them to backend server for verification. If verified, then route to a path defined with react-route-dom. The browser is Chrome. Here is the login component:

```
export default function ELogin () {
    console.log("from Elogin11");  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
    const [loginName, setLoginName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const authVal = useContext(authContext);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => { 
        console.log("from Elogin handleSubmit : ", event); //<<==NO show 
        let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/logins?password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&loginName=${encodeURIComponent(loginName)}`
        //let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/express_backend`
        let obj = {
            username:loginName,
            password:password
        };
        try {
            let employee = await helper.fetchpost(url, obj); //<<==fetch show up on backend node/express server
            console.log("fire up from react browser", employee); //<<==NO show 
            authVal.setEmpUser(employee.results);             
            //redirect
            return <Navigate to="/employee" />;
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error in login", err);
        };
       
    };

    const handleLoginName = (event) => {
        setLoginName(event.target.value);
    };

    const handlePassword = (event) => {
        console.log("handle password : ", event.target);  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
        setPassword(event.target.value);
    };
    console.log("before return Elogin");  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
            <Col sm={true}></Col>
            <Col sm={true}>
                <Form >
                    <h3 className="text-center" >Login Page</h3>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        
                        <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="登录名" onChange={handleLoginName} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        
                        <input type="password" className="form-control"  placeholder="密码" onChange={handlePassword} />
                    </div>

                    <Button onClick={()=>{console.log("button clicked") //<<==NO show; handleSubmit()}} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Login</Button>
                
                </Form>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={true}></Col>
            </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

However none of the console.log in `handleSubmit` gets printed in Chrome's console, and `Navigate` seems not fired as well.

UPDATE: Here is the current console output which is not showing console log inside of handleSubmit:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
ELogin.js:12 from Elogin11
ELogin.js:45 before return Elogin
localhost/:1 [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info: h-t-t-p-s:/-/goo.gl/9p2vKq) <input type=​"password" class=​"form-control" placeholder=​"密码">​
```

Comment: func handleSubmit is not called anywhere

Comment: handleSubmit is after onClick. The code is after // (for easy reading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    export default function ELogin () {
    console.log("from Elogin11");  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
    const [loginName, setLoginName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const authVal = useContext(authContext);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
            console.log("from Elogin handleSubmit : ", event); //<<==NO show 
            let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/logins?password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&loginName=${encodeURIComponent(loginName)}`
            //let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/express_backend`
            let obj = {
                    username:loginName,
                    password:password
            };
            try {
                    let employee = await helper.fetchpost(url, obj); //<<==fetch show up on backend node/express server
                    console.log("fire up from react browser", employee); //<<==NO show 
                    authVal.setEmpUser(employee.results);             
                    //redirect
                    return <Navigate to="/employee" />;
            } catch(err) {
                    console.log("Error in login", err);
            };
         
    };

    const handleLoginName = (event) => {
            setLoginName(event.target.value);
    };

    const handlePassword = (event) => {
            console.log("handle password : ", event.target);  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
            setPassword(event.target.value);
    };
    console.log("before return Elogin");  //<<==show up in Chrome's console 
    return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <Row>
                    <Col sm={true}></Col>
                    <Col sm={true}>
                            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <h3 className="text-center" >Login Page</h3>

                                    <div className="form-group">
                                            
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control"  placeholder="登录名" onChange={handleLoginName} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="form-group">
                                            
                                            <input type="password" className="form-control"  placeholder="密码" onChange={handlePassword} />
                                    </div>

                                    <Button  type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Login</Button>
                            
                            </Form>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={true}></Col>
                    </Row>
            </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

This will work, The issues in the code you posted I feel,

1. You are using two event listeners for the same submit event ( one from  submit button & other from form's onSubmit attribute), In that case you need to be careful about the order of execution.
2. The submitHandler is not preventing the form's default behavior (which is refreshing the page), That's we we are unable to see the consoles from submitHandler. To avoid this we need to call preventDefault function on the received event

Comment: Just cleaned the code and remove submit in Form tag (it works in either Form or Button tag). The handleSubmit is called and fetched from the backend (with status 200). The code behavior is the same after removing submit in Form tag

Comment: After adding event.preventDefault, the backend fall silent and was not called. Moving it to the end of handleSubmit works. But there is still no console output

Answer (score 2):

seems like the `onSubmit={() => {} }` on the form component is preventing that code from executing, please verify if it works after removing `onSubmit`

Comment: Just cleaned the code and remove submit in Form tag (it works in either Form or Button tag). The handleSubmit is called and fetched from the backend (with status 200). The code behavior is the same after removing submit in Form tag.